# How does one dynamically agree on a SenderCompID and TargetCompID in quickfixc in c++?

Tags: c++, quickfix

Suppose that I'm running a web-based exchange and a new customer signs up. I give that customer a new CompID and now I want to add that CompID to my acceptor. Do I have to restart my acceptor or can that be done dynamically?

It doesn't seem very scalable to have to agree on the CompID ahead of time and then sticking it in a configuration somewhere.

this is done in quicfixj, but I want to do that in quickfixc++ how should i do that?

Comment: `It doesn't seem very scalable to have to agree on the CompID ahead` You are opening a can of worms by doing this. `It doesn't seem very scalable` Why isn't it scalable exactly ?

Comment: can this be possible? if there is work around .Let us know.

Answer (score 1):

According to [how to create dynamic sessions using QuickFix](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/338242/How-to-create-dynamic-FIX-sessions-using-Quick-Fix) you can do something like:

```
SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings();

SessionID id1 = new SessionID(new BeginString("FIX.4.2"), 
        new SenderCompID("FixServer"), 
        new TargetCompID("Client1"), "Session1");
Dictionary d = new Dictionary();

d.setString("ConnectionType", "acceptor");
d.setLong("SocketAcceptPort", 5001);
d.setString("FileLogPath", "Log");
d.setString("StartTime", "00:00:00");
d.setString("EndTime", "00:00:00");
d.setString("FileStorePath", @"c:\fixfiles");
d.setBool("UseDataDictionary", true);
d.setString("DataDictionary", @"FIX42.xml");

settings.set(id1,d);
```

with the C++ equivalent to set up a dynamic session and then :

```
acceptor.setSessionProvider(socketAddress, new DynamicAcceptorSessionProvider(
settings, templateSessionID, application, messageStoreFactory, logFactory,
messageFactory));
```

I reckon the C++ equivalent is to setup a [Socket Acceptor](https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/blob/c3e9d06fb95dba4a9d70ec7870b153063e378340/src/C%2B%2B/test/SocketAcceptorTestCase.cpp)